# how to use a list as a parameter for SQL connection in python using pyodbc

Tags: python, parameters, pyodbc

I am learning python, and I am trying to pass a parameter as part of the WHERE clause. I am using pandas and pyodbc. Here is what I've tried so far. I first get the data for column c from a pandas dataframe, and convert it to a list called df_col, which has about 100 numeric values

```
df_col=df['data_for_colc'].tolist()
```

then, I execute the SQL statement:

```
execu = mycursor.execute(
"""
Select 
 columnA
 ,columnb
 ,columnc
where
 columnc in (?)
""",df_col)

rows = mycursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

I am able to connecto and download data from SQL server, but I am not able to pass parameters. I just need to be able to download those 100 rows based on the list I created with 100 values, but I get an error: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Your SELECT statement has no FROM clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax error is because you left out the `FROM` clause in your query.

Once you fix that, you need to have as many `?` in the `IN()` list as there are elements in `df_col`.

```
placeholders = ", ".join(["?"] * len(df_col))
sql = """
    SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE columnc IN (""" + placeholders + ")"
execu = mycursor.execute(sql, df_col)
rows = mycursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Comment: True, but the wrong number of parameter placeholders does not explain the error in syntax. The problem with the query stated in the question is more fundamental than that.

Comment: yeah, that's because he forgot `FROM tablename`

Comment: @roganjosh The other answer uses `.format()`, so I'll leave mine with string concatenation. But I've moved the joining out to another variable.

Comment: thank you. It was not working at the beginning, but I figured out it was missing some "" at the end. Thank you very much.

Comment: @barmar yes, I forgot the FROM in the SQL statement. my bad.

Answer (score 3):

you have to generate all those question marks...

```
execu = mycursor.execute(
"""
Select 
 columnA
 ,columnb
 ,columnc
where
 columnc in ({})
""".format(','.join("?"*len(df_col))), df_col)

rows = mycursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Comment: @Barmar why would I want a list... I can use`','.join()` with a string. It works fine as it is

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot that `join` will iterate over the characters of the string. Too much PHP/JS...